# Order a table from values in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table name 'Product'

```
ProductID   ProductName
1           A
2           B
3           C
4           D
```

Another table named 'ViewedProduct'

```
ProductID    Views    UserID
2            2        55
2            1        40
1            10       40
1            50       127.0.1
3            51       127.0.1
```

for UserID 55 the expected result should be

```
ProductID    ProductName
2            B
1            A
3            C
4            D
```

UserID 55 views should be at top and all other viewdproduct should come after it order by sum of their views. The product id 1 viewed by two different UserIDs thei total views is 60 that why it should come in second place. and product id 3 have 51 views it should come in third place.

> **Second Example :**

```
 ProductID    Views    UserID
    2            2        55
    3            3        55
    2            1        40
    1            10       40
    1            50       127.0.1
    3            51       127.0.1
    4            50       127.0.1
```

Now for UserID 55 , it should first sort the result based on UserID 55. Then comes the rest result. Now the expected result i need should be

```
ProductID    ProductName
3            C
2            B
1            A
4            D
```

Product ID 3 and 2 is not top because UserId 55 has viewed this 3 and 2 times respectively, the productid 1 is on the third place UserID 55 have not viewed this product. but their total views from viewed table is 60. And productID 4 comes last because userid 55 have not viewed this product but it total views from view table is 50. and so on..

-- Please comment if you need further explanation

Comment: And where is the logic?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Either your examples are wrong or I'm not getting it... Can you clarify why ProductID's 1 & 3 should be returned while there's no relation with UserID 55?

Comment: Missing table of ProductID related to UserID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited the query to include the userID in the join clause as I believe this is necessary. see fiddle here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ef18/1

```
SELECT
    Product.ProductID,
    Product.ProductName
FROM
    Product
    LEFT JOIN ViewedProduct ON Product.ProductID = ViewedProduct.ProductID AND ViewedProduct.UserID = @userID
WHERE
    ViewedProduct.UserID IS NULL
OR  ViewedProduct.UserID = @userID
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN ViewedProduct.Views IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE ViewedProduct.Views END DESC,
    Product.ProductID
```

To order by the following:
    UserViews,
    AllViews,
    ProductID

Use the following:

```
SELECT
        Product.ProductID,
        Product.ProductName
    FROM
        Product
        LEFT JOIN ViewedProduct ON Product.ProductID = ViewedProduct.ProductID AND ViewedProduct.UserID = @userID
        LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT
           ProductID,
           SUM(Views) AllViews
         FROM
           ViewedProduct
         GROUP BY
           ProductID) TotalViewedProduct ON Product.ProductID = TotalViewedProduct.ProductID
    ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN ViewedProduct.Views IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE ViewedProduct.Views END DESC,
        TotalViewedProduct.AllViews DESC,
        Product.ProductID
```

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7c08/7 have a look.. i am close.. for userid 40 product id 1 and 2 are top because they have 10,1 views respectively this is good but product id 4 should be in 3rd place because sum of their view is 80 and product 3 should be at last their visits sum is 54

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are asking here but if you want to return results from one of these tables and sort it by a column in another table just create a join between the main table and the table that holds the column you want to sort on. This will allow you to sort on columns in the joined table.

```
SELECT Product.ProductID, Product.ProductName
FROM Product
LEFT JOIN ViewedProduct ON Product.ProductID = ViewedProduct.ProductID
ORDER BY ViewedProduct.UserID
```

This however will not return the results you expect as UserID 55 has not viewed ProductID 1 or 3 and ordering will simply order ascending or descending.

If you want products viewed by UserID 55, you'll need a where clause:

```
SELECT Product.ProductID, Product.ProductName
FROM Product
LEFT JOIN ViewedProduct ON Product.ProductID = ViewedProduct.ProductID
WHERE ViewedProduct.UserID = 55
```

This will just return one row, unless there is more data than in your sample.

If you want to order by number of views try something like:

```
SELECT Product.ProductID, Product.ProductName
FROM Product
LEFT JOIN ViewedProduct ON Product.ProductID = ViewedProduct.ProductID
WHERE ViewedProduct.UserID = 55
ORDER BY ViewedProduct.Views
```